# Discrete Mathematics, Equivalnces"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The "≡ mod 3" relation is an equivalence relation on the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. List the equivalence classes.

I understand "≡ mod n" relation on **Z** is transitive. I just cant see how to start this problem, Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Two integers are congruent modulo $3$ if and only if they share the same remainder when divided by $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements which can be written as $3k+1$:

$$[1]=\{ 1,4,7 \}$$

Elements which can be written as $3k+2$:
$$[2]=\{ 2, 5\}$$

Can you write down the set of elements which can be written as $3k$?

Comment: 3k+1
[1]= {1,4,7}
3k+2
[2] = {2,7}
3k+3
[3]={3}
Repeats with single digit from there.

Comment: $[3]=\{ 3,6\}$, there are only $3$ equivalence class.

Comment: Oh opps thank you! So when I am looking at a question in the future like this it is basically the format when Mod 3, "3k+x" right? With x increasing by 1 and K part of the elements?

Comment: In general, I will pick an element, say $1$, find all element that is equivalent to it, that would form an equivalence class. Then I will move on to another element that is not in any equivalence class yet. Repeat.

Comment: Okay this helps a lot thank you, the book I have is really bad.